# How to make a devel enviroment on my app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, version

I wonder now about an option to have a devel version of my project on Heroku address. I mean, I have my project on the address **my-random-name.heroku.com** and here from my local directory I deploy my app.

Is possible from my local directory deploy my app to the other address, where I would check the new updates and if these updates will be ok, so I will deploy these changes to the **my-random-name.heroku.com** (here is my "bright" version of my app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - Heroku applications are just git remotes, so by pushing to a different remote you can deploy to a different application.

For instance:

```
git remote add production git@heroku.com:appname-production.git
git remote add staging git@heroku.com:appname-staging.git
```

will then allow you to deploy to each env with a simple push.

```
git push production master
git push staging master
```

If you're using different branches for development and production (a good idea) you can also deploy [fairly simply](http://neilmiddleton.com/deploying-topic-branches-to-heroku/)

Comment: That's lot of new information for me... so now when I deploy my app like "git push heroku master", so for adding **staging** mode I should in my app directory `heroku create staging-app` and then just `git remote add staging git@heroku.com:staging-app.git` and `git push origin staging`? Didn't forget I for something?

Comment: git push staging master

The third argument is the remote.

Comment: and about **taps** please? Usually I use `heroku db:push`, so how should look this command for staging version?

Comment: anything using the heroku cli you will need to explicitly pass the application name, `heroku db:push --app staging-app`

Comment: For clarity - You will need to create a new application on heroku for staging. You can push the same git repository to different applications. For your workflow: push to the staging app first, test it, then push to production app (this can all be done by using different parameters in the git and heroku commands as shown above).

Comment: @mc6688 thanks for comment, and what about database? I am accustomed to deploy always my database from localhost to heroku "heroku db:push". How can I move the database on stag app, and than on the production app?

Comment: You can add a parameter at the end to specify where you are pushing it: db:push [DATABASE_URL]